# Can not execute select queries while making a long lasting insert transaction

Tags: postgresql

I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL and I'm sure I'm missing something here.
The scenario is with version 11, executing a big drop table and insert transaction on a given table with the nodejs driver, which may take 30 minutes.
While doing that, if I try to query with select on that table using the jdbc driver, the query execution waits for the transaction to finish. If I close the transaction (by finishing it or by forcing it to exit), the jdbc query becomes responsive.

I thought I can read a table with one connection while performing a transaction with another one.
What am I missing here?
Should I keep the table (without dropping it at the beginning of the transaction) ?

Comment: Read this section in the docs [Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) and if it is not clear after that, then amend you question with the things you don't understand.

Comment: Obviously if you `drop` a table, you can't query it from a different connection. Every DDL statement acquires an exclusive lock on a table which means that no other transaction can access that table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that would be many not every.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DROP TABLE` takes an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, which is there precisely to prevent it from taking place concurrently with any other operation on the table. After all, `DROP TABLE` physically removes the table.

Since all locks are held until the end of the database transaction, all access to the dropped table is blocked until the transaction ends.

Of course the files are only removed when the transaction commits, so you might wonder why PostgreSQL doesn't let concurrent transactions read in the mean time. But that would mean that `COMMIT` may be blocked by a concurrent reader, or a `SELECT` might cause a system error in the middle of reading, both of which don't sound appealing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put all the information together